# Macro to fill in cells from a column sequentially when I click on a button

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to figure this out.

This is my layout:

[image: screenshot of the layout]

As you can see, I have 2 buttons.

What I would like each button to do is:

1. Each time I click `YES`, it will insert a `Y` in a cell in a specific range.
2. If I click `YES` again, it will automatically insert a `Y` in the next cell under the previous one in the same column.
3. If I click `NO`, it will also continue down the column and insert an `N`.

How to make the buttons' output to always use the next free cell?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Can you share the code you have so far, so we can see where to help you?

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to assume the rest of your code is done and what you need is some method to get a row for inserting your values. Here's a snippet that works best if your data isn't very large and you happen to prefer loops:

```
Dim rNext as Long
rNext = 2   'First used row in column F
Do Until LenB(Range("F" & rNext).Value) = 0
    rNext = rNext + 1
    If rNext = ActiveSheet.Rows.Count Then Exit Do
Loop
```

And here's a solution that's more robust and quite a bit faster:

```
Dim rNext As Long
rNext = Range("F2:F" & Cells.Rows.Count).Find(vbNullString).Row
```

As you might be able to tell from the second example, you could do this directly with the following:

```
Range("F2:F" & Cells.Rows.Count).Find(vbNullString).Value = "Y"
```

Comment: +1 Good solution. OP, also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11169920/1161309) for some additional clarification.